# Implementing a C++17 compliant STL container?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I'm not interesting for practicality (I know I can and should use any of the already provided STL containers). It's solely for education purposes. Are there any resources for this? I realized looking through the standard that a lot of traditional methods from articles I read online (`std::iterator`) have been deprecated.

Comment: Before digging into Standard I'd start with reading and understanding "named requirements" describing STL containers (kind of concepts) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req E.g. for `std::vector`: "(for T other than bool) meets the requirements of Container, AllocatorAwareContainer, SequenceContainer , ContiguousContainer (since C++17) and ReversibleContainer. "

Answer (score 2):

> Implementing a C++17 compliant STL container?
>
> Are there any resources for this?

Yes. The official source is the C++ standard. Container requirements are specified in the section named `[container.requirements]`.